# Turn off autocomplete in Light Table

Tags: clojure, lighttable

How do I turn off autocomplete in Light Table?

Might `user.behaviors` looks as so

```
[
 [:app :lt.objs.style/set-skin "dark"]
;; Automagically closes parentheses
 [:app :lt.objs.settings/pair-keymap-diffs]

 [:editor :lt.objs.editor/wrap]
 [:editor :lt.objs.editor/line-numbers]
 [:editor :lt.objs.style/font-settings "Menlo" "9" "1.2"]
 [:editor :lt.objs.style/set-theme "monokai"]

 [:editor.clojure :lt.objs.langs.clj/print-length 1000]
 ;; Turn off autocomplete
 [:editor :lt.plugins.auto-complete/auto-show-on-input]
]
```

I have tried adding `[:editor :lt.plugins.auto-complete/auto-show-on-input]` but it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need to do:

```
 [:editor :-lt.plugins.auto-complete/auto-show-on-input]
```

Answer (score 5):

To turn of textual hints use:

```
[:editor :-lt.plugins.auto-complete/textual-hints]
```

If you want to turn off textual hints for say just javascript you do

```
[:editor.javascript :-lt.plugins.auto-complete/textual-hints]
```

If you want to turn off autocomplete all together:

```
[:editor :-lt.plugins.auto-complete/show-hint]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
:- {:editor [:lt.plugins.auto-complete/auto-show-on-input]}
```

What you want to do is subtract it from the diffs in the file. See this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/light-table-discussion/T0gyicrEPFw) for more details and an example behaviors file snippet.

Comment: I tried about four version of this (in the new format) `[:- :editor [:lt.plugins.auto-complete/auto-show-on-input]]`
   but neither of them worked. Including `- :editor [:lt.plugins.auto-complete/auto-show-on-input]` and various others.